# MudBlazor dynamic tabs through foreach in component

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, mudblazor

I`m trying to use a foreach loop in a MudBlazor Component. So the Tabs have a dynamic length depend on amount of categories.

```
<MudTabs Elevation="2" Rounded="true" ApplyEffectsToContainer="true" PanelClass="pa-6">
    @foreach (Category category in categories)
    {
        <MudTabPanel Text="@category.CategoryName">
        </MudTabPanel>
    }
</MudTabs>
```

I have no error when execute it, just don't show up. It seems that mudblazor components are unable to use looped elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:
It is nessassary to bind a index with tabs to the tabs

```
<MudTabs @bind-ActivePanelIndex="_index" Border="tru....
```

Then u can add Tabs in @code

```
foreach (Category category in categories)
        {
            _tabs.Add(new TabView { Content = category.CategoryCode.ToString(), Name = category.CategoryName, Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }
```

Details in MudBlazor Documentation in "Advanced Dynamic Tabs"
https://mudblazor.com/components/tabs#advanced-dynamic-tabs

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to include the MudBlazor css file?

---

> Note: If you're installing on a fresh Blazor template make sure to remove everything in your site.css and remove the bootstrap.min.css completely from either index.html or _Host.cshtml.

> In the HTML body section of either index.html or _Host.cshtml add this:

```
<script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
```

https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#a161e105-3665-4477-8427-77b800c64065

Comment: As seen in the edits, I have added the changes as recommended in the documentation